# "No matching function for call to ... " when using CGImage in C++ source

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I'm porting a game written in C++ and OpenGL to run on iOS and OpenGL ES. The original version uses libpng and jpeglib for loading image data as sprites, and I want to replace these with CoreGraphics functions.

At the top of the C++ source file which contains the image loading functions, I've added the following:

```
#ifdef TOUCH_VERSION
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#else
#include <png.h>
#include <jpeglib.h>
#endif
```

The `TOUCH_VERSION` compiler flag is defined (and is working, since it's not complaining about missing png.h and jpeglib.h). The problem I'm having is that it's not recognising any CGImage functions. For example:

```
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(path);
```

results in the error `ImageBuffer.cpp:166:42: No matching function for call to 'CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename'`. Initially when I added the CF and CG includes, it autocompleted the CoreGraphics type and function names so I presumed the header import had worked, but when I built I got errors that NSString and other Objective C types were not defined. I added `-x objective-c` to the C flags, and `-x objective-c++` to the C++ flags and it resolved this error, but then the error above appeared.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: and `path` is of type `const char*`?

Comment: Thanks @StephanLechner - you're absolutely right, and I just made the exact same discovery. I was forgetting that in C++ you can have the same function name but with different argument types, and that using the wrong argument type won't necessarily lead to an error that an unexpected type was sent to the function. I've been using Objective-C too long ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, sorted. I realised that the C++ function was using std::string as the CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename is expecting `const char *` as the filename. When I changed this to `CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(path.c_str())` it stopped complaining about the lack of a matching function.